# Yes, this is the legendary wall

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, connect-wall

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #42: Wordless Connecting Walls](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7045/fortnightly-topic-challenge-42-wordless-connecting-walls)</sup>

---

This is it. This is the very wall.

His life, his work — this wall was the center of it all. One simply cannot imagine his fame, greatness, and legacy without thinking about how this wall was always there to witness all his ups and downs. There might as well be "Mr. H was here" carved on it.

Having a good time was never a major part of his life. Well, never except once: and yes, this wall bears evidence to it, too. Sure, now it may be covered in posters and signs and brush strokes and suspiciously identical splashes of paint, but legend has it, if one knows where to look, what connections to make, the wall will speak of his glory days. In true [connect-wall](/questions/tagged/connect-wall) fashion, one must find the four linked groups of four objects each and uncover the truth.

[image]

> **What four-letter word describes the time of the year that went particularly great for him? Who is this mysterious Mr. H?**

Comment: This is really well done! Though I wonder if (rot13) "Ze. U" zvtug unir tvira vg njnl. V thrffrq obgu cnegf sebz gur qrfpevcgvbaf jvgubhg jbexvat gur chmmyr. Gung fnvq vg'f terng fgbelgryyvat naq pyrneyl n tbbq chmmyr. Znlor tnir n ovg gbb zhpu njnl jvgu gur anzr naq lryybj lbyx fcynfurf gubhtu?

Comment: @bob that's a good point, didn't consider that possibility at all. Oh well, remind me to never write a murder mystery :p

Comment: :) Though seriously, good writing and fun puzzle. Please do keep this up.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I first noticed that

> This might become a connect wall of nursery rhymes

because

> I saw "McDonald's" and "farm" at the top

and

> I was able to look up what the image at Row 1 Column 2 was by searching the keywords in the image-- turns out, it was a [HAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_accumulation_diode),

which confirmed my suspicions.

And the more images I was able to get, the more my suspicions were confirmed.

> From left to right, top to bottom:
>  FARM, HAD, MCDONALD'S, [JILL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jill_Biden) (ooh, topical);
>  [DOWN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down_feather), OLD, ROBIN, UP (or is it "WENT UP"?);
>  FALL, [JACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Sparrow), [COCK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_valves#Specific_types), HILL; and finally
>  BRIDGE, LONDON, KILL, WHO.

Now of course, the groups are

> Old MacDonald Had A Farm (OLD, MCDONALD'S, HAD, FARM),
>  Jack and Jill (JACK, JILL, UP, HILL),
>  London Bridge is Falling Down (LONDON, BRIDGE, FALL, DOWN), and
>  Who Killed Cock Robin (WHO, KILL, COCK, ROBIN).

This is just purely amazing:

> If you trace paths as shown above from spot to spot (e.g. forming the title for Old MacDonald, you would go from the OLD image to the MCDONALD'S image to the HAD image and finally to the FARM image), you will get this:
>
>  [image]
>
>  which seems to spell **FALL**!

Thus we now know that

> **FALL** was a great time for Mr. H.

And finally

> I was able to infer that Mr. H was Mr. **Humpty Dumpty**.

This must be correct because

> Humpty Dumpty is also part of a nursery rhyme, which is the theme of this connect wall.

But more than that, it also confirms the answer to the first question! You must remember

> that the nursery rhyme starts off as "Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall, Humpty Dumpty had a great **fall**!"

Some other things to note:

> - The flavor text all makes sense now.
>  - The color of the spots and lines was not accidental either-- after all, because Humpty Dumpty was an egg, when he fell down the wall, yellow would have splattered on the wall. (Edit: [In The Sphinx's Lair chatroom, OP confirmed that that was not his original intention.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56057880#56057880))

Comment: This is correct, of course, nicely done!

Comment: I could not stop grinning all the way when I realized what events were going on in this puzzle, and it was so fulfilling, so satisfying, to get to the end. Thank you for this awesome puzzle @Ankoganit !

Comment: Oh wow, I LOVE this puzzle! Great job solving it so quickly oAlt and amazing work again @Ankoganit - so impressive you've managed to create another connect wall that's so thematically perfect!